# Highchart: How to change y-axis title text inside angularjs controller?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-directive

I have created highchart directive

```js
App.directive('hcChart', function ($parse) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true
        ,
        template: '<div><div class="chart"></div></div></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.chart = new Highcharts.chart(element[0], {

                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: "Date"
                    },
                    type: 'datetime'
//                    labels: {
//                        step: 24
//                    }
//                    ,
//                     tickInterval:  2  
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: "Value"
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
                ,
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                chart: {
                    opacity: 0.51,
                    backgroundColor: "white",
//                    plotBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
                    plotBackgroundColor: 'white',
//                    width: 1600,
                    height: 800,
                    zoomType: 'x',
                    resetZoomButton: {
                        position: {
                            x: -140,
                            y: 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    crosshairs: {
                        width: 3,
                        color: 'black',
                        dashStyle: 'shortdot'
                    }
```

how to change y-axis title text inside controller.
As i want to show different unit for different selection.

inside controller i'm using $scope.myseries for data and $scope.categories for x-axis date time.

html code

```
<hc-chart   id="container" categories="{{myCategories}}" series="{{mySeries}}">Placeholder for generic chart </hc-chart>
```

how to use $scope to update y-axis?
i tried using

```
$scope.yAxis[0].setTitle({text : "abc"})
```

but its throwing errror. not defined property.
any help please!

Comment: Why not using https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng? There are also examples in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/pablojim/highcharts-ng/tree/master/jsfiddles/basic/)

Comment: should i add var inside directive? but how to get $scope variable to change title text as it wouldn't identify the scope and changed dropdown selection?

Comment: @beaver isn't there not much difference between highcharts-ng directive and hc-chart directive? as i 'm using $watch to update series based on dropdown selection and $scope to pass to directive that watch the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change yAxis title inside angularjs controller, we need to set its property:

```
                    Highcharts.charts[0].yAxis[0].setTitle({
                    text: $scope.NAME
                    });
```